# How can i read this column from my database

Tags: php, pdo

I have a column in my database that i am having trouble with.

the column is named `Actual` and the table looks like this

[image]

I need it to be read like this. **[129.74, 130.74, 129.50]**

any help is appreciated

**What i have tried**

Test1

```
  $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT Actual FROM csvhoejde1");
  $sth->execute();

  /* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set */
  $result = $sth->fetchAll();
  echo'<pre>';
  print_r($result);
  echo'</pre>';
?>
```

print_r result:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Actual] => 129.74
        [0] => 129.74
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Actual] => 130.74
        [0] => 130.74
    )
```

Test 2

```
  <?php
$sql = "SELECT `Actual` FROM `csvhoejde1`";
$test = $db->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

echo'<pre>';
print_r($test);
echo'</pre>';
?>
```

Result:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on
>   array

Comment: So, what's the result of that `print_r`?

Comment: ill edit my question with the print_r result

Comment: Use `$db->query("SELECT Actual FROM csvhoejde1");` instead of the `$db->prepare()` and `$db->execute()` since you don't need to bind any value

Comment: If it's just that you get two sets of values - try `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0)`

Comment: Thanks! That worked!

Comment: Can you make a answer with that `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0)` for some reason i can't answer it myself

Answer (score 0):

```
$upit = "SELECT Actual FROM csvhoejde1";

$conn = new mysqli('localhost','user','pass','db');

$result = $conn->query($upit);

$array = [];

while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $array[] = $r;
}

$string = "[";


    foreach ($array as $ar){
        $string .= $ar['Actual'].",";
    }


    $string = rtrim($string,',')."]";

    echo $string;
```

Comment: I can't really use it since it uses mysqli_fetch_assoc. doesn't work with my code. but i am sure that it works for those who can.